# Python logger not printing Info

Tags: python, logging

Looking at the python docs, if I set my logger level to INFO, it should print out all logs at level INFO and above.

However, the code snipper below only prints "error"

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.info("Info")
logger.error("error")
logger.info("info")
```

Output

```
error
```

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: This `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)` should work

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `logging.basicConfig` to set a default level and a default handler:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

logger.info("Info")
logger.error("error")
logger.info("info")
```

prints:

```
INFO:root:Info
ERROR:root:error
INFO:root:info
```

The `logging` module is powerful yet confusing. Look into [the HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial) in the docs for a tutorial. I've made my own helper function that logs to stderr and a file that I've detailed on [my blog](https://www.bbkane.com/blog/logging-in-python/). You might like to adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Does this mean it is impossible to set different loggers to different levels of verbosity? I would have thought that the OP's expected behavior was what we'd need to set different levels of verbosity for different loggers.

Comment: Test this, but you should be able to override the global setting for specific loggers

Answer (score 16):

The reason for this behaviour is that there are no logging handlers defined.
In this case the handler "logging.lastResort" is used.
Per default this handler is "<_StderrHandler  (WARNING)>".
It logs to stderr but only starting from level "WARNING".

For your example you could do the following (logging to stdout):

```
import logging
import sys
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))
logger.info("info")
```

Output

```
info
```

In the [howto](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.FileHandler) you can find other useful handlers.

Comment: This reply correctly pointed out that when one invokes a new instance of Logger also a handler has to be specified, which is not explained in the accepted answer.

Comment: This answer solved the issue for me, given I'm creating a new Logger instance.